# AWS RDS Host Access

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-rds, scp

Is it possible to SSH to instance hosting the RDS database

For example I have a database in PostgreSQL running on AWS RDS I want to access the instance which RDS is being host on be able to access postgreSQL data directory via SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to SSH to instance hosting the RDS database

**Its not possible** to SSH into RDS instances. These are managed instances by AWS, and you have no means of accessing them other then connecting to the databases.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot SSH into the underlying OS of an Amazon RDS instance. This is by design. Amazon Relational Database Service is a managed service that makes it easy to set up, operate, and scale a relational database in the cloud. This would not be manageable at scale if customers were able to log into and modify the OS.

If you need access to the operating system, you can always run and manage your own database server on Amazon EC2. This means however, that you are responsible for keeping both the OS and the DBMS secure and up to date.

Comment: Thanks for info :)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was helpful. Thanks.